# How to use Google analytics authorization without web browser interaction using service accounts?

Tags: google-analytics, authorization

I am trying to access google analytics data without the need for a user to interact with a browser to authorize this access -- in this case, it is our own data that we wish to display outside of Google Analytics.

Google describes service accounts here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtAuthorization

and I think based on the description that this is what I am looking for. It is necessary to follow the steps to obtain things used in the following code:

```
 GoogleCredential credential = new  
                      GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId("758873802454-   s8o6hgkjjn8rm15so46pvrqu1lgn4squ@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
                .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(AnalyticsScopes.ANALYTICS_READONLY))
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("C:\\Users\\jeff.miller\\Downloads\\67ed856e6b6b55e846f53e78e76b28141c98eeff-privatekey.p12"))
                .setServiceAccountUser("758873802454-s8o6hgkjjn8rm15so46pvrqu1lgn4squ.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                 //.setService("AIzaSyCM1FlW4fs38NPSOesXULeSnBlpYd783Xk")
                .build();
```

The p12 file is downloaded and we also get a new service account with client id and email address that I put I think in the correct places in the constructor code above. Moreover there is the need to do configuration from the Google console. I have gotten various error messages, most recently: "Invalid impersonation prn email address" but I have also gotten 
messages indicating that the account did not have permission no matter what I tried.

The code is based on examples that are obsolete -- for example, in the example setServiceAccountScopes took a string rather than a singleton.

It would be great to find an up-to-date Java example including hints about configuration in the console, that gives me the ability to access Google Analytics without browser interaction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better example, adapted from [Google Drive documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts).

```java
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.Analytics
import com.google.api.services.analytics.AnalyticsScopes;
...

/** Email of the Service Account */
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "<some-id>@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

/** Path to the Service Account's Private Key file */
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = "/path/to/<public_key_fingerprint>-privatekey.p12";

/**
 * Build and returns an Analytics service object authorized with the service accounts.
 *
 * @return Analytics service object that is ready to make requests.
 */
public static Analytics getAnalyticsService() throws GeneralSecurityException,
    IOException, URISyntaxException {
  HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
  JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
  GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
      .setTransport(httpTransport)
      .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
      .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
      .setServiceAccountScopes(AnalyticsScopes.ANALYTICS_READONLY)
      .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
          new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
      .build();
  Analytics service = new Analytics.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
      .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
  return service;
}
```

You also have to grant user access to the email `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL` to your Google Analytics Account. This has to be done on the Analytics Admin UI, just go into Admin, User Management and add it as you would add a normal gmail access.

Comment: Thanks -- I will try it out and name my first born for you if it works!

Comment: The argument to "setServiceAccountScopes" is not a singleton as in my example -- can you tell me what version of the jars I should be using?

Comment: I hardnly use java so I haven't even tested this. Just adapted from Drive docs. Have you tried replacing it with the singleton?

Comment: So in what sense is it a "better" example?

Answer (score 0):

Jeff,

I m using Google Drive Api, which uses the same GoogleCredential.

In the initialisation, you are setting account user as 758873802454-s8o6hgkjjn8rm15so46pvrqu1lgn4squ.apps.googleusercontent.com, it should be changed to your google email, with which you created the project

GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
                .setServiceAccountUser(**userEmail**)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                        new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
                .build();

**userEmail** - your google user id